# Using obfsproxy + OpenVPN on Windows (client)

Tags: obfsproxy, openvpn

I want to use OpenVPN through opfsproxy (any version of that). It works with the following instruction (server and client sides) but I can't relay on this file because it is not released by Tor Project.

Do you have any suggestion for client side. I mean any suggestion to have a reliable opfsproxy.exe file to give it to my clients. Then they will be able to use obfsproxy as the tunnel?

https://www.ivpn.net/knowledgebase/141/Windows---I-canandsharp039t-connect-from-China-or-Vietnam-or-Iran-etc.html